# C Integer range must meet 3 different conditions

Tags: c, if-statement, int

If I wanted to limit the range of values to be assigned to an integer to three different conditions. eg; Must be between 9 and 95 and also be divisible by 5 would this be the correct way to accomplish this?

I've been told that i can have multiple conditions as long as they are separated by && but I am having little success with my code.

```
if (input >= 5 && input <= 95 && input %5)
```

Comment: A number is divisible by 5 if num % 5 == 0. You are not checking for that.

Comment: Please read up what the `%` operator does; it does not return a `true` if the LHS is divisible by the value on the RHS.

Comment: @DeiDei thank you, sometimes the answer is obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine to me, except for this line.

```
if (input >= 5 && input <= 95 && input %5)
```

The expression `input % 5` returns the remainder of `input/5`. You want `input` to be divisible by 5, which happens when `input % 5` returns a remainder of 0. Since C interprets 0 as false, and pretty much all other integers as true, this expression will do exactly the opposite of what you want it to do. Try using

```
if (input >= 5 && input <= 95 && (input % 5 == 0))
```

That should do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are a *number* of issues with your code as it stands. First, the outright bugs:

- The expression `input % 5` will give you the remainder when divided by five. This means you will get zero if it *is* a multiple, non-zero otherwise. Unfortunately, zero is treated as *false* so this will only be true if `input` is *not* a multiple. The correct expression is `(input % 5) == 0`.
- If you enter something that cannot be interpreted as an integer, the `scanf` will fail and `input` will be left at whatever value it was beforehand. This should be caught and acted upon, by checking the return value - this gives you the number of items successfully scanned so should be one.
- Your code seems to return the value if okay but return *nothing* if it's invalid.

Next, while not bugs, these things are my personal preferences which can make code easier to read and maintain:

- I prefer to *explicitly* separate sub-expressions so I never have to worry about precedence rules (provided it doesn't make the expression unreadable in the process). To that end, I would make the full `if` statement `if ((input >= 5) && (input <= 95) && ((input % 5 == 0))`.
- I'm not a big fan of the `if (condition) transferControl else ...` construct since the `else` is *totally* superfluous.
- I also prefer error catching to be done in a localised fashion at the start, catching problems early. Only after all checks are passed do you do the success portion.
- A function (assuming it is a function, which seems likely) should generally do *one* thing, such as check if the value is valid. Writing issues to standard output is probably best left to the caller so that the function is truly re-usable. It would be better to have a function do the check and return some value to indicate whether or not there was a failure, along *with* the value if valid.
- It's usually better to use `puts("something")` rather than `printf("something\n")`. The `printf` call is best left to where you actually *need* to do argument formatting.

---

Taking that all into account, the code that I would posit would be along the lines of:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool InputValidRangeAndMultiple(
    unsigned *pValue,
    unsigned minVal,
    unsigned maxVal,
    unsigned multVal
) {
    unsigned input;

    // If no unsigned int available, error.

    if (scanf("%u", pValue) != 1) return false;

    // If value invalid in any way (range or multiple), error.

    if ((*pValue < minVal) || (*pValue > maxVal)) return false;

    if ((*pValue % multVal) != 0) return false;

    // Value is now deemed okay.

    return true;
}
```

Calling that function can be done thus, with the prompts and errors handled *outside* the "input and check" function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned value;

puts("Enter Value.\nValue must be divisible by 5 and within 5 and 95...");
if (! InputValidRangeAndMultiple(&value, 5u, 95u, 5u)) {
    puts("Invalid input...");
    returnOrDoSomethingIntelligent();
}
// The 'value' variable is now valid.
```